# Get raw query string in flask

Tags: python, flask, query-string

Is there a way to get the raw query string or a list of query string parameters in Flask?
I know how to get query string parameters with `request.args.get('key')`, but I would like to be able to take in variable query strings and process them myself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [several `request` attributes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path) that let you access the raw url:

> Imagine your application is listening on the following URL:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/myapplication
> ```
>
> And a user requests the following URL:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html?x=y
> ```
>
> In this case the values of the above mentioned attributes would be the following:
>
> ```
> path          /page.html
> script_root   /myapplication
> base_url      http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html
> url           http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html?x=y
> url_root      http://www.example.com/myapplication/
> ```

These, eventually with the help of [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), will let you extract the information you need:

```
 >>> from urlparse import urlparse
 >>> urlparse(request.url).query
 'x=y'
```

Answer (score 5):

request.query_string also seems to work.

Comment: Includes everything after the first ? (even if there are subsequent ?s)